# Irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ of degree $n$ is the minimal polynomial of exactly $n$ elements of $L$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

The problem goes like the following:

> Let $F$ be a finite field, and $L/F$ an extension of degree $n$.
>
> (a) Show that any irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ of degree $n$ is the minimal polynomial of exactly $n$ elements of $L$.
>
> (b) Suppose $|F|=p$. Determine, in terms of $p$, the number of irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$ of degree 3, and also the number of irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$ of degree 9, respectively.

My approach for (a) is: If $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ in $F[x]$ and if $\alpha\in L$ is a root of the polynomial, then we have $F(\alpha)\cong \dfrac{F[x]}{(f(x))}$ and $[F(\alpha):F]=n$. Since $[L:F]=n$, $L=F(\alpha)$. I wanted to say that $L$ is Galois over $F$ so that it would contain all the roots of $f(x)$ and thus $f$ is irreducible and has exactly $n$ roots in $L$. But I don't know how to justify that $L/F$ is indeed a Galois extension. Also, it seems to me that if $|F|=p$, then $F=\mathbb{F}_p$ and $L=\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ but I don't know if these would be helpful.

For part (b), using Mobius inversion formula, the number of irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$ of degree 3 is given by
$$\frac{1}{3}\sum_{d|3} \mu(d)p^{3/d} = \frac{1}{3}(p^3-p).$$
However, I don't think this would be the purpose of this problem. Now I've noted that $|L|=p^n$ as it can be viewed as a vector space over $F$ of dimension $n$. Using (a), since the irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ of degree 3 is the minimal polynomial of 3 elements of $L$, there would be $\dfrac{p^3}{3}$ such irreducible polynomials as $|L|=p^3$, which does not match with the result given by the Mobius inversion formula. Can someone help me out here? Many thanks!

**Edit:** I still need some help on proving part (a), though. If anyone has anything, please leave a comment or a solution. That would be really helpful!

Comment: In your next-to-last sentence, you forgot to account for the $p$ elements of $L$ that are already in $F$. Their irreducibles are linear, and taking account of this, you again get a count of $(p^3-p)/3$

Comment: @Lubin Thanks for the comment. Yeah, I've thought about that. But when I was considering the number of irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$ of degree 9, I get $(p^9-p)/9$ by the same reasoning, while the Mobius inversion formula gives $(p^9-p^3)/9$. Am I missing something in this case?

Comment: Well, once again, you have to exclude the elements in $\Bbb F_{p^9}$ that are already in $\Bbb F_{p^3}$. Remember that you want to count only the elements of the biggest field that aren’t in any smaller field.

Comment: @Lubin Ohhh, I see now. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Well, since no solution so far has been posted, I'll give what I figured out.

First, Part (a):

**Proof**: Suppose $|F| = q$ (note that here $q$ is not necessarily a prime so in turn not necessarily a prime subfield of a finite field, it could be a power of prime, since any finite field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ for some prime $p$ and integre $r\ge 1$), and suppose $L/F$ is an extension of degree $n$, i.e. $[L:F]=n$. Viewing $L$ as a vector space over $F$ of dimension $n$, we see that $|L| = q^n$. This says that $L \cong \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$. We claim that $L/F$ is a Galois extension. Note that $L^{\times}$ (is cyclic being the mutiplicative group of $L$, which is finite) has order $q^n-1$. So for any $\theta\in L$, 
$$\theta^{q^n-1}=1\implies \theta^{q^n}=\theta\implies \text{$\theta$ is a root of the separable polynomial (by derivative test)  $x^{q^n}-x$ over $F$.} $$
Therefore, $L$ is a subfield of the splitting field of $x^{q^n}-x$ hence is the splitting field as $|L|=q^n$. So such $L$ (an extension of $F$) exists and is Galois (also we have, by definition, $|$Gal$(L/F)|=[L:F]=n$).

Now suppose that $f(x)\in F[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ having $\alpha\in L\setminus F$ as a root. Then all roots of $f$ are contained in $L$ since the extension is Galois. These $n$ roots are distinct elements in $L$ since $f$ is irreducible over a perfect field (namely, the finite field $F$) thus separable. It then follows that $f$ is the irreducible polynomial for the $n$ roots in $L$ and so $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $n$ elements of $L$. (a) is proved.

Part (b) is solved (see the comments given by Lubin above).